# Issue regarding insertion in sql

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to insert multiple values in one cell in mysql database for example I have ingredients like egg,salt,pepper,chillipowder.These ingredients must be in one cell to retrieve the recipe containing those ingredients altogether
Will anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to **SO** first of all please consider following the rules of asking a question and attach to your question minimum code sample of what you done or screenshots what you want!.

You can do what you want if you have those values in an array by just encode it to **JSON** and when ever you want to re read those values you can just do decode the **JSON**

Comment: Thank you and I'll follow rules from next time onwards but I have another question..I need to store statically those ingredients in my database in single cell.How can I store them manually?

Comment: If you are willing to use the **JSON** format, it should be looking like this: `{"first_index_key":"first_index_value","second_index_key":"second_index_value"}`